# Code igniter query with autoincrement id return true even if id is wrong

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter

So recently I'm making a simple CRUD app with Codeigniter.

My table has id field that is an auto increment field.
My model has a function called getById.

```
public function getById($id){
        return $this->db->get_where($this->_table,["id" => $id])->row();
    }
```

In my table, I have 1 field with ID of 1.

If I try to query with wrong ID, it return empty.

However, when I try to input something like 1 followed with string like

> 1test

it did return the field with id 1 in my database. I don't know if this is how it should be or is it a bug.

Answer (score 0):

Surely Codeigniter is casting your string to integer.

> [PHP intval() manual says](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functhttps://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.phpion.intval.php):
>   Strings will most likely return 0 although this depends on the leftmost characters of the string. The common rules of [integer casting](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php#language.types.integer.casting) apply.

So, if you need to throw an error on invalid entries, you must validate them first, maybe using [is_int()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-int.php) to allow only integer type or [is_numeric()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php) to allow strings containing only numbers.